# remove nuget package restore from solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I added the recent nuget package restore feature to a solution using 'Enable NuGet Package Restore':
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

However it broke my build server and I didn't have the time to fix it, so I wanted to remove it. There's no option for that as far as I know, so I removed the following line manually from all my *.csproj files:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

The problem now is that every time my *.csproj files are checked out or open my solution, the line is automatically added again, breaking my build if I accidentally check it in :(

Any ideas how I can remove it permanently?

UPDATE: despite the answer below it still keeps coming back when opening the solution, anyone with the same problem?

Comment: Can't you just rollback the changeset in Source control?

Comment: well it was quite a big changeset, but thanks to your comment I did have a look, and it seems it also added a .nuget folder in the solution path, deleted that as well to see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Did you manage to fix the build server? (and is it teamcity?), because the import project line you quote above is what is causing my teamcity builds to fail

Comment: @Baldy No we are using TFS Build and I didn't really look for a solution, just removed it (still planning on diving into it later)

Comment: I've created an issue for the NuGet team to fix this problem. Please go up-vote it at https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3756

Comment: [This IFix tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b8ba97b0-bb89-4c21-a1e2-53ef335fd9cb) helped me to identify and correct the numerous locations within files that needed to be updated.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

I didn't look very well, there's another property added to the project files:

```
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
```

Just have to remove this as well as all these lines manually from all *.csproj files:

```
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

**UPDATE:**

Turns out it's a persistent little bugger, if you're manually editing your project files, **make sure to close the solution and delete all the lines from the project at once**, otherwise they're just added again once the project reloads...

**UPDATE2:**

Delete the .nuget folder from the solution root too

**UPDATE3:**

A later version of NuGet adds another section that you need to remove:

```
 <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

**Update4**

Inside the `NuGet.Targets` located in the `.nuget` folder, there is another section that gets added to new projects... switch it to false.

```
<!-- We need to ensure packages are restored prior to assembly resolve -->
<BuildDependsOn Condition="$(RestorePackages) == 'false'">
    RestorePackages;
    $(BuildDependsOn);
</BuildDependsOn>
```

Comment: I have found that there's also a `<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />` at the end of the .csproj file that needs to be manually removed.

Comment: @TimDog that's part of the question :)

Comment: HA! *backs away slowly* :)

Comment: This thing has been plaguing me as well. If your projects are in many different solutions the package restore feature causes mounds of problems.

Comment: "Make sure you close the solution" is actually of key importance here, as VS2010 seems to cache csproj/msbuild files (without picking up certain modifications). I didn't notice this behavior in VS2012, but this has plagued me a lot when modifying these files within VisualStudio.

Comment: Didn't have to delete .nuget from the folder, but you sure have to close the solution.

Comment: Restart VS2010 after modifying all the .csproj file of all the projects in your solution. You can also comment these two lines <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>

Comment: I've created an issue for the NuGet team to fix this problem. Please go up-vote it at https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3756

Comment: @ShaunRowan well almost a year after posting this question/answer I am using nuget on the (TFS) build server, and it sure beats checking in all packages into source control!

Comment: There are some cases where one needs to check the packages into source code control and nuget is not allowed.

Comment: One thing that can make this more convenient - as Nitin answered - a script implemented by Owen Johnson that makes the necessary edits in all csprojs recursively: https://github.com/owen2/AutomaticPackageRestoreMigrationScript/blob/master/migrateToAutomaticPackageRestore.ps1

Comment: The answer helped me to solve an opposite problem. The project was created in VS2017 solution and then was copied to different VS2015 solution. And nuget packages for the project were not restored until I not added the sections, that are listed in your answer

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim glad it helped... Though even in your case I'd still remove the MSBUILD targets and just run 'nuget restore' from the command line, or use some pre-build script.. Using MSBUILD targets to restore packages is fundamentally flawed as you might reference targets in nuget packages that haven't been restored yet. Which build server are you using?

Comment: We are using TeamCity. The problem is that VS2015 solution Is a  legacy monolith, that we prefer not to touch, unless it’s absolutely necessary. Anyway I will check, how safe will be to change restore mode. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 48):

To disable Nuget Package Restore:

1. Delete .nuget folder
2. Remove specific lines from all .csproj files

Lines to remove:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
```

Note: Make sure you do all changes in one go before reloading solution or else it will add them back.

This is based on the following article: 
http://bartwullems.blogspot.no/2012/08/disable-nuget-package-restore.html

Also, you might want to double-check that this option is disabled: 
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: I've created an issue for the NuGet team to fix this problem. Please go up-vote it at https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3756

Comment: I've used the IFix tool with great success in cleaning up repos with many projects. It basically automates these steps. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b8ba97b0-bb89-4c21-a1e2-53ef335fd9cb

Comment: The .nuget folder is hidden and you need to remove it from the *directory* not only the project.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't it this setting here?

**Options...** -> **Nuget Package Manager** -> **[uncheck] Allow Nuget to download missing packages**

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio Professional + Resharper 8.2

Comment: I deleted the packages folder and cleared the package cache to fix my issue. Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't update the .proj files after - so the problem returns -- but good to do it here too :-)

Comment: The output window shows this while building: `Restoring NuGet packages... To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'` it is just a confirmation that this should be the way to go.

Comment: This is unrelated to Nuget Package Restore. Old versions of VS had a [context menu item for projects titled “Enable Nuget Package Restore”](https://i.imgur.com/16dtLpW.png) which would make a `.nuget/` folder and modify your `.csproj` to reference a `.targets` file. You were supposed to commit the `nuget.exe` to your VCS (eww, unsolving the problem nuget solves!) and ugliness like that. Nowadays, `msbuild /restore` exists and VS’s built-in package restore. The OP is asking how to remove the old, bad way of doing things—not how to disable VS’s correct built-in package restore support.

Answer (score 5):

Solutions currently using MSBuild-Integrated package restore can be migrated to Automatic Package Restore. From what I understand, this should help those who are encountering CI build issues.  (Please correct me if I am mistaken).

Please refer to the document on the nuget website: Migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

There is information there for converting with and without TFS.

David Ebbo also posted some information at http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Answer (score 3):

We actually have a blog post about it and at the end of the post a powershell script was mentioned to help with the migration.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Answer (score 3):

NuGet has a blog post about migrating to automatic package restore:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

There is a **powershell** script referenced in the blog post that will take care of **removing the necessary lines automatically** (and recursively):
https://github.com/owen2/AutomaticPackageRestoreMigrationScript/blob/master/migrateToAutomaticPackageRestore.ps1

Offering a Disable NuGet Package Restore option directly is marked as Won't Fix:
https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1883

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. What I ended up doing:
1) go into each project .csproj file in the solution, open it in notepad then removed the  portion of the xml and saved.

2)Then I removed the all of the package.config files in the entire solution.

3)Then I had to remove the .nuget and package folders.

At this point, I had a completely NuGet free solution.

4)Then I manually referenced any needed DLLs and hit compile and the solution ran like a champ without the NuGet packages being needed.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the accepted solution to no avail using 2012.  This did work though,

1. Completely close the VS
2. Update the `<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>` to `<RestorePackages>false</RestorePackages>` and delete the `<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />` line
3. Also renamed the `nuget.exe` to `nuget.exe.NotExe`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still needing to clean up a project using the old style NuGet package restore, the IFix tool available [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2014/06/11/converting-projects-to-use-automatic-nuget-restore.aspx) automates the process.

Just run the installer (`IFix` will be added to `PATH`) and then run the following:

```
IFix nugetrestore --fix
```

You can run it in check mode first to see what it will clean up:

```
IFix nugetrestore --check
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your solution directory where you have `[$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets]
.nuget` folder and `nuget.targets` file under it delete the folder,
and change remove lines from your **csproj** for once last time.

The problem won't come back to bug you again.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *packages.config* file within your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally enabled this "package restore" option while opening my project in VS2012 RC and started getting errors that looked something like:

"Error      1             Unable to locate 'C:\FolderX\SomeProject.nuget\nuget.exe'"

To fix the error I followed the above instructions, opened open each project file in notepad and removed that RestorePackage line.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by taking these steps:

1) make sure you take a backup of all your current checked-out files changes.

2) physically delete the solution folder from your C:\ (path that is mapped to TFS).

3) get latest from TFS for your solution.

4) copy (if any) your changes from the backup you took in step-1.

hope that helps !

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the exact same problem and tried to remove all .nuget and RestorePackage tags from the project files but one project just wouldn't reload not matter how thoroughly I examined it for .nuget and RestorePackages tags. I guess there's some hidden references to this somewhere.

In the end it was easier to just copy the files and create a new project and import it to the solution.

Answer (score -9):

Nuget sucks. Just remove nugets and remove or comment package elements from packages.config in root directory of the projects where this is a problem. Use direct references into some lib folder instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
    <!--<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />-->
  </packages>
```

Comment: It 'sucks', as any other product, if you don't know how to use it and don't make an effort to understand it.

Comment: That's ture, but in my optinion nudged doesn't give you enough control over your project.

Also the Nuget GUI needs some serious upgrades. 

1. Its not intuitive, 

2. Its hard to manage the package 

3. Its hard to turn off restore 

4. Downloads unneeded packages 

5. Sometimes its not able to restore pacakges

Comment: I agree to some extent, though I think it really beats having no package manager at all. Seems like they're working on the serious GUI upgrades for nuget 3.0: http://blog.nuget.org/20141112/nuget-3.0-preview.html