# How to downgrade NuGet from 2.8.6 to 2.8.5 (or remove completely)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nuget

Recently my projects stopped building with a noninformative message:

========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

If I set build verbosity to some other setting it does not produce any more info.

My solution contains a project that I want to build.

```
MySolution\
    MyProject\
```

Next, I tried a command line build:

Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe MySolution.sln

And this produces following error:

> MySolution\MySolution.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>   "D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" (default target) (6) ->
>   D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : 
>   Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 
>   [D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
>   D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error MSB3073 : The command ""D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\packages.config" -source ""
>   -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution\ "" exited with code 1. [D:\Visual Studio\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]

This particular message:

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
```

was a hint to a search that resulted in assumption that the problem lies in Nuget 2.8.6 that was build for .NET 4.5 yet trying to access type in .NET 4.0 mscorlib.

So I have two options:
Downgrade Nuget 2.8.6 to NuGet 2.8.5. I have tried that but have not succeeded.

```
Tools -> Extension Manager… ->  NuGet Package Manager -> Uninstall
```

Then I tried to install NuGet 2.8.5 found at:
http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/612846
Downloaded the extension and installed, but I ended up with 2.8.6 as visible in Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio.
A that point I would like to know how to make a clean uninstall and install of version 2.8.5.

The other option is to remove NuGet completely and live without it. I have deleted .nuget folder, deleted sections in .csproj file that mention nugget, but still, my project does not build.

I don't know what else I could  do. I need to make a build.

Comment: @StephenBrickner Hmmm, why do you think that? Have I missed something?

Comment: Ok I may have missed something in your question. System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute was moved in 4.5. Can you set the version of your project to 4.5 or does it have to be 4.0?

Comment: @StephenBrickner Yes, it has to be 4.0. Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue that they do not plan to fix (https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1287). This person claims to have found a way around the issue which you can try: https://jacstech.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/error-when-deploying-a-net-4-0-project-that-was-downgraded-from-net-4-5-to-a-net-4-0-server/

Comment: @StephenBrickner I have seen that. In that post he downgrades the project itself fron 4.5 to 4.0, not nuget. And I know it is a known issue. But there is no solution. As it is now, the VS stopped building. Period.

Comment: Right, I don't think Nuget is your issue here. When you updated it something was changed in your project settings that is now looking to build at a different target version which is causing the error you are getting because it is looking for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute in a different assembly than it used to be in under 4.0

Comment: @StephenBrickner I don't even have 4.5 on my computer. I jave checked packages.config: it targets 4.0. i have looked in MyProject.csproj: no reference to 4.5 there.

Comment: NuGet command line 2.9 is out which fixes the nuget problem. As far as I could tell at a first glance. I am still not able to build my project.