# Visual Studio 2019 "Unable to parse version value '1.0.0-preview2' from packages.config"

Tags: vb.net, nuget, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to work with Microsoft's Graph API at my company, and I'm following [the online documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth) to get this done. I'm working in VB .NET and I am importing the Microsoft.Graph.Auth package as it says, and when I build the code, I get the error above. Please see screenshot below too.

I'm unable to find a solution for this online. I cannot tell if it's something to do with the fact that it's a preview package? It's strange since this is what Microsoft instructs us to do...

```
Imports Microsoft.Identity.Client
Imports Microsoft.Graph
Imports Microsoft.Graph.Auth

Public Class Graph
    Private clientId As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GraphClientId")
    Private redirectUri As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RedirectUri")
    Shared tenantID As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GraphTenant")
    Private clientSecret As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GraphSecret")
    Public authProvider As ClientCredentialProvider = Nothing
    Public Sub Initialize()
        Dim confidentialClientApplication As IConfidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithTenantId(tenantID).WithClientSecret(clientSecret).Build()
        authProvider = New ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetAllUserTasks()
        Initialize()
        Dim graphClient As New GraphServiceClient(authProvider)
        Dim tasks = graphClient.[Me].Planner.Tasks.Request().GetAsync()
        Debug.Print(tasks.Result.Item(0).Title)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Would greatly appreciate the help!

[image]

Comment: Rather than updating the project-based NuGet.exe in the .nuget dir, this SO answer can help remove it to use Visual Studio's built-in package restore functionality instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713616/remove-nuget-package-restore-from-solution

Answer (score 6):

What version of nuget.exe are you using? You can get the version number by executing `. C:\cps2\.nuget\NuGet.exe` in a console window.

If the version number is lower than 4.3.0, then download the latest version from https://www.nuget.org/downloads, and replace the current `C:\cps2\.nuget\NuGet.exe` with the new one. This is because [Microsoft.Graph.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/1.0.0-preview.2) uses SemVer v2.0.0 which is not compatible with NuGet clients older than 4.3.0. This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#semantic-versioning-200.

Comment: Thanks so much, I did not realize that I had to replace the .exe file manually. I tried this, and now get errors for every nuget package I have ever installed. For each one, it says `could not find a part of the path C:/cps2/ /packages/{package_name}`. I'm not sure what this means, and could not find much help online.

Comment: Nuget can update itself given the right command line arguments.

Comment: what might this "right command" be?  just tried `Install-Package NuGet.Client -Version 4.2.0` and it didn't update that .exe file in `cps2/.nuget`

Comment: I also tried `Install-Package NuGet.Client -Version 4.3.0-beta1-2418` - also did not update the `.exe` and still got errors for Microsoft.Graph.Auth

Comment: I am in the same boat now. I updated all my NuGet packages using Visual Studio Package Manager and updated nuget.exe too. However now every single project fails to build with the same error!